# How RDBMS B+ Tree Indexing works for Select Query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, rdbms

I learnt that B+ Trees are used for implementing RDBMS , and Now i want to implement an RDBMS in C/C++ ,  i've read about B+ Trees and also saw the SQLite.

I have a conceptual doubt of how the Search Query works on Database, we store (key,values) on the B+ Tree ,Now say i had a table

with columns {id,name,phone,address}

and i have to search for the record with phone = 'xyz' , how will database use B+ Trees to efficiently get that record.

Is it complete O(N) search on the records or optimized?

Answer (score 1):

It [is a complete *O*(*N*) search](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_tables_without_indices) if you do not have an index.
It [is optimized](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_lookup_by_index) if you have an index.

Comment: What is the best way to implement an optimized version that can support optimization for all the columns?     
such that search on any column is optimized

Comment: Multiple B-tree indexes, or a full-text index.

Comment: Thank you , How does SQL retrive query such as 
name = 'abcd' and phone = 'xyz' , does SQL uses Multiple b-tree or full text index. 

I just wanna do an SQL Project in C/C++ so want to get some idea on how actually the search query retrives values efficiently.

Comment: Read the links.

Answer (score 0):

**Average case O(logb(n))**

**Worst Cast O(n)**

A B+ tree is a blanced tree , it works more like binary search tree specially in MYSQL . its implementation can be varied.